# Composition of desiccant

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment

Most types of desiccation packages use silica gel, but are there any that use calcium oxide instead? Here's my reasoning:

1. Calcium oxide absorbs water, forming calcium hydroxide.
2. Adding a (used) package to water produces a slight amount of heat (I may be imagining this).
3. The solution stays cloudy even after sitting for a while.
4. The solution almost immediately turns clear upon addition of vinegar.

At this point, I'm pretty sure it *is* calcium oxide and hydroxide in this package, but I just wanted to make sure first. For point 2, I should note that it is very humid in the place that I live, so it would make sense that most of the calcium oxide is converted into calcium hydroxide, and therefore not much heat is produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, calcium oxide can be used as an desiccant.

The following quote is an excerpt from [this site](https://www.sorbentsystems.com/desiccants_types.html):-

> Calcium oxide is calcinated or recalcinated lime having a moisture adsorptive   capacity of not less than 28.5% by weight. The
>   distinguishing feature of calcium oxide is
>   that it will adsorb a much greater amount of water vapor at a very low
>   relative humidity than other materials. It is most effective where a
>   low critical relative humidity is necessary, and were there is a high
>   concentration of water vapor present.
>
> Calcium oxide removes water from a package very slowly, often taking
>   days to reach its maximum capacity. As calcium oxide adsorbs moisture,
>   it swells. Proper desiccant packaging is required for effective use.
>   For these reasons, its use has been limited to primarily the packaging
>   of dehydrated foods.

This following is a table which compares the properties of various dessicants taken from [this site](https://www.sorbentsystems.com/desiccants_charts.html):-

[image]

And the following graph depicts the adsorption capacity of various dessicants:-

[image]

For more information click on the following sites:-

1. http://www.ohe-chem.co.jp/e_qa.html
2. http://www.agmcontainer.com/support/selecting-desiccant
3. https://www.usaemergencysupply.com/information-center/self-reliance/food-storage-frequently-asked-questions/types-of-desiccants